# pg_basebackup: could not open transaction log file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

**Version: Postgres 9.6 (Windows)**

I am attempting to do a pg_basebackup but I receive the following error

```
PS C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin> .\pg_basebackup -h 192.168.0.185 -Fp -D D:\pg-test\ -P -U postgres -Xs
pg_basebackup: could not open transaction log file "D:\pg-test\/pg_xlog/000000010000000000000002": No such file or directory
52189/52189 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace
pg_basebackup: child thread exited with error 1
```

I attempted to start the server (standalone mode) but receive the following error in log file

```
2021-07-20 12:04:22 CAT LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-07-20 11:51:32 CAT
2021-07-20 12:04:23 CAT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-07-20 12:04:24 CAT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-07-20 12:04:25 CAT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-07-20 12:04:26 CAT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-07-20 12:04:27 CAT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-07-20 12:04:28 CAT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-07-20 12:04:29 CAT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2021-07-20 12:04:30 CAT LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
2021-07-20 12:04:30 CAT FATAL:  could not locate required checkpoint record
2021-07-20 12:04:30 CAT HINT:  If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/backup_label".
2021-07-20 12:04:30 CAT LOG:  startup process (PID 1172) exited with exit code 1
2021-07-20 12:04:30 CAT LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2021-07-20 12:04:30 CAT LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my file path. Even though its a windows host I needed to specify the directory as `D:/pg-test/`